# How do you connect a Nest thermostat to a Noritz CB199 DV combi boiler?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, boiler

I have only one zone and I'm using the internal boiler pump. I do not have any zone valves. I have a 24v transformer and a White Rodgers 90-370 relay.

Comment: What make and model is your boiler?

Comment: Noritz CB199 DV

Comment: and thank you for answering!

Comment: Please [edit] that info into the original question. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: What are you using for an air handler, or are you driving radiant/baseboard heat with this sytem?

Comment: [Installation manual for your boiler](https://support.noritz.com/download.php?file=Literature%20Page/Installation%20Manual/CB199_180_0616.pdf&field=InstallationManual), BTW